# Is "thirty past seven" acceptable?

Tags: expressions, time

If it is seven thirty, we can also say "half past seven". I am wondering whether "thirty past seven" is acceptable.

Comment: **twenty-five** past is common, we don't use thirty past.

Comment: seven thirty :)

Comment: I'm more of a 'thirty till 8' kinda guy... ;)

Comment: It is acceptable; it is correct and will be understood. It is not idiomatic.

Comment: It depends what you mean by "acceptable".  If you mean "will native speakers understand me", the answer is yes.  If you mean "would a native speaker say this", then I believe the answer is no.  Of course, there are several dialects that I haven't encountered yet, so one day, I might meet a native speaker who says "thirty past seven"; but it hasn't happened yet.  So it's probably best if you avoid saying this.

Answer (score 13):

***"[Half past](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/half-past-one-two-etc) seven"*** is the common expression. The following picture may help you and please see ***[here](http://www.vocabulary.cl/Basic/Telling_Time.htm):***

[image]

Comment: Instead of "five to eight", many people say "five till..." or "five of...".

Comment: @Joe, or just "five minutes till" without stating the hour, since usually people know the time at least to *that* degree of accuracy.

Comment: Also, "It's quarter past..." is wrong. It should be "It's a quarter past..."

Comment: @Joe Not where I am from; "five till" would mark you as definitely foreign (but would be understood) and "five of" would likely be met with utter incomprehension. Indeed the first time I heard an American say "quarter of 12" I thought they meant quarter past 12.

Comment: @Glen_b, in my experience, these terms vary quite a bit from region to region.

Comment: @Glen_b, to me "five to..." sounds odd, unlike "five till..." which sounds normal.  Since I'm not sure exactly which terms would be best for the asker, I'd just want to point out that the various options exist.

Comment: Note that these expressions are understood, but rarely used, in American English.

Comment: A lot of Stephen King characters seem to say "quarter of".  I've always assumed it was a north-east USA thing, since many of his books are set in New England.  I've never met a real person who says it.

Comment: Note that this "answer" doesn't actually answer the question: is "thirty past acceptable".  It just describes some common ways of expressing some times.

Comment: @undo: What you say has *some* justification, but I think it's ott to say dropping the article is actually *wrong*. Note this from [BBC Learning English:](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/radio/specials/1535_questionanswer/page63.shtml) *If you asked me the time at 6.15, I might well say “**quarter past six**”, instead of “**a quarter past six**” – but that’s pretty conversational, and “**a** quarter” is **more normal** if we’re speaking carefully, or writing.*

Answer (score 4):

A native speaker would probably recognize what you mean, by analogy to what native speakers actually say (1 minute past seven, twenty-nine  past seven, fifty-five past seven, and possibly fifty-nine past seven), but native speakers do not actually use *thirty past*, except if they wanted to be "cute" or call attention to themselves by using a non-typical expression.

And, in my experience  native speakers will not say *fifty-nine* past seven, since it's kind of "idiotic" not to say, instead, one minute till eight. However, forty past and even fifty past are not uncommon.

Comment: In my experience native speakers will not say any number higher than ***twenty-nine minutes** past seven*. Also, they will *always* include the explicit noun ***minutes*** for all numbers that aren't multiples of five (but not ***fifteen***, which is always rendered as ***[a] quarter***). Nobody says *It's twenty-six past seven*, for example. It's the same principle past the half-hour, in that nobody says *It's eleven to nine* (that's always *It's eleven **minutes** to nine*).

Comment: @FumbleFingers As often,  your experience is just that.

Comment: That's why I specifically said *In my experience*. But I've been around a long time, and heard a *lot* of people use these constructions over the decades. Long enough to notice that younger people are much less likely to use the *X [minutes] **to** [next hour]* construction simply because they see more *digital* time displays rather than clock face hands.

Comment: From [BBC Learning English:](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/radio/specials/1535_questionanswer/page63.shtml) *In ordinary conversation, what most people say is “five past”, “twenty past”, “twenty-five to”, “a quarter to” and so on….Interestingly, we usually don’t say “four past”, or “six past” – we put in minutes there. We say “four minutes past”, “six minutes past” and we drop minutes with the fives: “five past”, “twenty past”.*

Comment: My experience accords with @FumbleFingers; I'll add that I think the digital aversion to the **X to Y** construction is spreading; I'd be somewhat surprised to hear *twenty-seven minutes after 2* from my college students—I'd expect it to be *two twenty-seven*—and I'm fairly certain that my children would even only say *two-fifteen* rather than *quarter past/after two*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: In my experience, Americans don't always say *"minutes"*. See *Chicago*'s song "Twenty-five or -six to four". (Middle of the night.) But we don't say "thirty-five past three". And digital clocks mean we're saying *"three thirty-five"* much more often.

Answer (score 4):

Other answers have shown that there is a lot of variation in what is "normal".

The answer to the original question, though, depends on what you mean by "acceptable".

If you mean "will I be understood?" - the answer is yes.

If you mean "will I sound natural" - the answer is no.

"thirty past" is not in the set of "normal" variations of how we say time.

If you want to say the word "thirty" then you add it after the time like

> "ten thirty".

This is very normal and actually applies to any number of minutes.   I'd go as far as to say that this is the "safest" way to construct a time: say the number of minutes after the hour.

> "ten ten"
>
> "ten twenty five"
>
> "ten fifty nine"

are all natural sounding.

Only the less-than-ten numbers need a slight adjustment.

"ten eight" would not even be recognised as a time, and "ten two" sounds like "ten to", which is means "ten minutes to the hour" the same as "fifty minutes past the hour"!

Instead, for minutes less than ten

> "ten oh two"

is the way we say it, presumably because that makes it "look like" a time:

> 10:02    ten oh two

(where "oh" is the alternative pronunciation of the number zero)

Answer (score 2):

"Thirty past seven" would be readily understood, but "sound funny" -- it would take an extra few seconds to process.

Times are generally expressed as laconically as possible:  "What time is it?" "Quarter after"/"Quarter past", "Ten to"/"Ten of" if the relevant hour is probably known, e.g., the questioner and questionee have been waiting together, and the question has been asked recently enough.  If the hour is needed, the questioner can then ask "quarter after what?"/"ten of what?"

Some people answer generally:  "Quarter after" for any time in the range 13-17 after, if there's no reason to suppose exactness is desired.

And of course some try to answer precisely:  "my watch shows 13 after 7" / "according to my watch, 9 minutes before 7".

One can say "15 after/past 7", but for some reason not 30 or 45.  The same is true of times before an hour:  "15 before 7" sounds slightly stilted but okay, but "30 before 7" sounds odd and "45 before 7" *very* odd.

Comment: It'd be polite of the person(s) who down-ticked me 2 points to explain their reasoning.

Answer (score 0):

*Half past seven* would be the most natural way to express this, however *seven thirty* is far more common. The past/to expressions are not extremely common. I more frequently here *quarter till* (short for *quarter until*) or *quarter after*, with the hour unspoken and implied when relative to an event happening now. I very, very rarely hear anyone say *ten to eight*, I almost always hear *ten till eight* or *ten till* here in the northwest US. *Half past* is used more than *half after* but *seven thirty* is by far the most common way to express it.

The *past* and *to* expressions are more commonly used in literature, having a distinct pacing and warmth that the common form of time does not.

Comment: In certain parts of the USA, you'll hear 'ten *of* 8', which just goes to show you, and apparently others, that there's many flavors when it comes to telling time.

Comment: When you say "here in the northwest", which country are you referring to?  Lots of countries have northwests.

Comment: Northwest US. Fixed!